# Bot dialog doesn't start

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

i'm here to ask of any of you guys know why my bot won't start the dialog?
I'm a new guy in the world of bots and read a lot of it, but can't seem to fix this.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});


var luisAppUrl = process.env.LUIS_APP_URL || 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/.......';
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session, args, next) {
  session.send('How can i help you ?')
  session.endDialog();
  next();
});

bot.recognizer(new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisAppUrl));


bot.dialog('Location', [
  function (session, args, next) {
  var intent = args.intent;
    var locations = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Location');
     var location = session.dialogData.location = {
       title: title
     };
    // session.send()
    if (!locations){
      builder.Prompts.text(session, 'From which settlement do you want to know the location? ')
    } else {
      next();
    }

  },
  function(session, results) {
    var location = session.dialogData.location;
    if(results.response){
      note.text = results.response;
      // session.send('Our company is located in Antwerp')
    }
  }
]).cancelAction({
  matches: /^(cancel|nevermind)/i,
  confirmPrompt: "Are you sure?"
});
```

So my bot just keeps crashing and doesn't start the bot.dialog ?
Can you guys see what is wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by crashing, are you getting an error?  If so what is it?  Are you just testing on the emulator or another channel?  Which bot builder SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot is crashing because you're instantiating the `UniversalBot` class twice:

```
var luisAppUrl = process.env.LUIS_APP_URL // etc
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session, args, next) {
  session.send('How can i help you ?')
  session.endDialog();
  next();
});
```

Try removing the first `bot` so your code is just:

```
var luisAppUrl = process.env.LUIS_APP_URL // etc

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session, args, next) {
  session.send('How can i help you ?')
  session.endDialog();
  next();
});
```

**EDIT:**

To reach the `'Location'` dialog, you'll need to add a `triggerAction()` to your `dialog`.

```
bot.dialog('Location', [
  function (session, args, next) {
    // ...
  },
  function(session, results) {
    // ...
  }
]).triggerAction({
  matches: 'Location' // What your intent from LUIS is called.
}).cancelAction({
  matches: /^(cancel|nevermind)/i,
  confirmPrompt: "Are you sure?"
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!